# SessionAuthenticationModule Cookie Handler not creating HttpOnly secure cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, session-cookies, wif, claims-based-identity

I am using System.IdentityModel to authenticate users in an ASP.NET MVC4 web application using forms auth with a claims principal. (code based on this article: http://brockallen.com/2013/01/26/replacing-forms-authentication-with-wifs-session-authentication-module-sam-to-enable-claims-aware-identity/)

My ClaimsBasedAuthenticationService class issues the SAM cookie from the SessionSecurityToken, and all has been well...except that I just now noticed that it is not creating the session cookies as HTTPOnly or requiring them to require SSL.  When I debug the code, I can see those properties on the CookieHandler object are set correctly in the debugger, but the final session cookie that is created simply doesn't have the HTTPOnly and Secure flags marked.

I have the web.config lines to set these to true explicitly as such:

```
<system.web>
  <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms ... requireSSL="true" />
  </authentication>
 ...
</system.web>
<system.identityModel.services>
  <federationConfiguration>
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" hideFromScript="true" />
  </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

Can someone tell me if there's something else I am missing in order for my FedAuth cookies to be hidden from script (HTTPOnly) and require SSL?

Comment: someone suggested adding the attribute lockItem="true" to the httpCookies element, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same implementation and do not see your issue using Fiddler2.  However maybe the issue is related to your debugging tool?  In IE10 debugging tools the secure and http only flags are only displayed when the cookies are first received.  If you check using Chrome debugging tools you should see the flags displayed correctly on all requests.

Comment: Chrome dev tools do not show it either.  I tried w/ Fiddler2, but it wont' even show the entire request, only a "tunnel to" the hostname.  Not sure why Fiddler doesn't show the request/response details like the dev tools.

Comment: Have you setup Fiddler to Decrypt HTTPS traffic?  See Tools | Fiddler Options then the HTTPS tab); effectively a man in the middle attack, but you get to see what you need to see for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this working?  I've been using basically the same code and it's all fine.

I can't see that the following suggestions have anything to do with anything, but the only things I can suggest, are to set the cookie lifetime

> ```
> <cookieHandler hideFromScript="true" requireSsl="true" persistentSessionLifetime="30" />
>
> <forms loginUrl="/Whereever" timeout="30" requireSSL="true" />
> ```

and

> ```
> <system.webServer>
>   <modules>
>     <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
>   </modules>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

Comment: I haven't worked on that project in a while now, but if I recall, I think the attribute was being set correctly, and the dev tools were just lying :)...or at least that's what I like to think.